# How To Break Inheritance and Add Permissions to a Document Library Folder

Tags: sharepoint, permissions, directory

I've read a quite a few articles so far trying to figure out how to break inheritance of a library folder, then add permissions to it.  For example, I have a library named DIST0000, I've created a folder called 'Folder1' and I want to programmatically set permissions on 'Folder1' as I have many, many folders.  I'm no great sharepoint or C# programmer, I'm just trying to figure it out. :)

Can this be done?

How?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What articles have you read?

Answer (score 0):

```
// get a reference to the folder (this assumes path points to a valid folder)
SPFolder folder = SharePointConfiguration.Site.GetFolder(path);

// get a reference to the Sharepoint group collection
SPGroupCollection spc = SharePointConfiguration.Site.SiteGroups;

// get a reference to the group who’s permissions you want to modify for the folder above
SPGroup group = spc[groupName];

// create a role assignment from the group reference
SPRoleAssignment roleAssignment = new SPRoleAssignment((SPPrincipal)group);

// break role inheritance for folders/files because they will be having permissions separate from their parent file/folder
folder.Item.BreakRoleInheritance(true);

// update the role assignments for the group by adding the permissionSet “TestPermissionLevel” which is a custom
// permissionset I created manually…you can easily use any of the built-in permission sets
roleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add(SharePointConfiguration.Site.RoleDefinitions["Test Permission Level"]);

// apply the new roleassignment to the folder.  You can do this at the listitem level if desired (i.e. this could be SPfile.Item…. instead of SPFolder.Item)
folder.Item.RoleAssignments.Add(roleAssignment);
```

Comment: Thanks!  Actually, I have that exact code but it's giving me :Error 2 The name 'SharePointConfiguration' does not exist in the current context c:\spadmin\spadmin\sharepoint administration\windowsformsapplication1\form1.cs 73 31 WindowsFormsApplication1

Comment: Also, I'm dealing with Active Directory (which I guess I should have told you that) groups, not sharepoint groups.  I get that error for several things, not just the SharePointConfigureation.  Path also does it.

Comment: replace "SharePointConfiguration.Site" with this.Web or Spweb object it you are using windows client. using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Url))
            {
                using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                {}}

Comment: Now the 'SiteGroups' and 'RoleDefinitions' statements are giving an error.  Says no extension method.  What does that mean?

Comment: Remove .site also. Use web.sitegroups

Comment: Umm....now it'saying groupName cannot be found. So it cannot find the group. I defined groupName as a string variable. string groupName = @"domain\testgroup admin"; Can't seem to find it in Active Directory.